# TLP Wifi works BETTER on battery than on AC

Tags: 20.04, wireless, power-management, tlp

I installed TLP a couple of months ago.
(I was having a problem with my Bluetooth disconnecting after 3 seconds of inactivity, installing TLP and going to `/etc/tlp.conf` and changing `USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB` from `0` to `1` fixed it)

I had not used my laptop in the last 10/15 days (during the holidays) and updated everything as soon as I got back. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I have the impression that updating, my wifi started working terribly, disconnecting all the time. Surprisingly, the wifi seemed fine if I was on the battery, and I discovered that it worked normal simply if a ran `sudo tlp bat` instead of `sudo tlp start` independently on being or not connected to AC.

I was able to fix the issue last night by going to `/etc/tlp.conf` and changing `RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC` to `auto`.

This morning I updated the BIOS to see if it fixed it, and so far it seems that setting `RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC` back to the default value no longer influences the wifi performance, and my wifi connection is stable again in both tlp modes.

**However, by making several tests on the speed of the connection, I discovered that my internet speed is about 20% faster if I run `sudo tlp bat` compared to `sudo tlp ac`.**

All of these issues seem to be related, but I cannot understand what is happening. I have been using Ubuntu for 10 years, and never got such a weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the Wi-Fi driver. Why wouldn't you want to stay with RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=auto if the performance is better? You may also consider using RUNTIME_PM_ENABLE to set only the Wi-Fi card to auto https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/runtimepm.html#runtime-pm-enable

Comment: Changing `RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=auto` no longer influences the quality of the wifi. It no longer keeps disconnecting and connecting, but the internet speed is smaller on ac than on battery.